# Cómo puedo hacer que el valor de una variable se mantenga constante en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, variables

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
      Alter table xyz
      drop constraint PK_Cod
      
      Alter table xyz
      add cosntraint PK_Cod2 primary key clustered(campoID)
      on [Primary]
      ----------------
    --Aqui empieza segundo bloque de codigo
      Declare cont int=1
      Declare @prt int
      Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
      Set @prt = Select count..................... (consulta que me bota un valor entero: puede ser 3)
      while @cont <= @prt
      Begin
      Set @SQL='---código que elimina archivos--'
      exec sp_executesql @SQL;
      Set @cont = @cont+1;
      End;
      ----mas código-----
```

El proceso es asi, primero tengo que ejecutar los alters que estan antes del Declare. En ese orden. Luego paso al while que necesita del @cont para ejecutar el script que contiene. pero este @cont se va comparar cada vuelta con el @prt.

El problema es que cuando ejecuto el bloque de código de arriba del declare, el valor de @prt se hace cero y pues ya no puedo ejecutar bien lo demás. Lo que requiero es mantener ese valor, atraparlo de modo que cuando vaya al bloque del declare( y dsps entre en el while) el valor no me cambie a cero.

Nota: El valor de @prt, el resultado del select count... que le asigno. si lo ejecuto por separado me da un numero entero mayor a cero. Si ejecuto el bloque del while por separado y le asigno el entero de frente si me funciona.

Comment: antes del `declare`, no hay forma de cambiar el valor de la variable, porque no está declarada. Puede ser que ese código cambie de manera indirecta el valor de la variable, agregando o quitando registros que luego coincidirán con el `select count` que se ve que le asignas. Como ya te han dicho, sería mejor que prepares un [mcve] para que se entienda lo que dices, porque la explicación no me deja nada claro cuál es tu situación.

Comment: Listo, ya mejore el código y explico mejor que es lo que requiero. Y si efectivamente el bloque de código antes del declare me afecta la variable. Ese es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que las variables como su nombre lo dice, son variables, ahorita pueden contener cierta información y después otra.

Lo mejor es que lo declares como una constante ya que tu mismo lo acabas de decir. La constante será fija y no sufriría cambios.

Comment: Creo q encs me explique mal. El valor no es constante ya que esa consulta el select count, me arrojara diferentes valores segun sea el caso. Yo quiero hacerlo constante. De alguna manera atraparlo y cuando ejecute el bloque de arriba y lo vuelva cero, en la variabale se mantenga su valor de antes.